# Cannot write dict object as correct JSON to file

Tags: json, python-3.x

I try to read JSON from file, get values, transform them and back write to new file.

```
{
  "metadata": {
    "info": "important info"
  },
  "timestamp": "2018-04-06T12:19:38.611Z",
  "content": {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "name test",
    "objects": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "url": "http://example.com",
        "properties": [
          {
            "id": "1",
            "value": "1"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Above is a JSON that I read from file.
Below I attach a python program that gets values, creates new JSON and write it to file.

```
import json
from pprint import pprint


def load_json(file_name):
    return json.load(open(file_name))


def get_metadata(json):
    return json["metadata"]


def get_timestamp(json):
    return json["timestamp"]


def get_content(json):
    return json["content"]


def create_json(metadata, timestamp, content):
    dct = dict(__metadata=metadata, timestamp=timestamp, content=content)
    return json.dumps(dct)

def write_json_to_file(file_name, json_content):
    with open(file_name, 'w') as file:
        json.dump(json_content, file)


STACK_JSON = 'stack.json';
STACK_OUT_JSON = 'stack-out.json'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    json_content = load_json(STACK_JSON)
    print("Loaded JSON:")
    print(json_content)

    metadata = get_metadata(json_content)
    print("Metadata:", metadata)
    timestamp = get_timestamp(json_content)
    print("Timestamp:", timestamp)
    content = get_content(json_content)
    print("Content:", content)

    created_json = create_json(metadata, timestamp, content)
    print("\n\n")
    print(created_json)

    write_json_to_file(STACK_OUT_JSON, created_json)
```

But the problem is that create json is not correct. Finally as result I get:

```
"{\"__metadata\": {\"info\": \"important info\"}, \"timestamp\": \"2018-04-06T12:19:38.611Z\", \"content\": {\"id\": \"1\", \"name\": \"name test\", \"objects\": [{\"id\": \"1\", \"url\": \"http://example.com\", \"properties\": [{\"id\": \"1\", \"value\": \"1\"}]}]}}"
```

It is not that what I want to achieve. It's not correct JSON. What do I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

> You're converting a `dict`  into a `json` and then right before you write it into a file, you're converting it into a `json` again. When you retry to convert a `json` to a `json` it gives you the `\"` since it's escaping the `"` since it assumes that you have a value there.

### How to solve it?

> It's a great idea to read the `json` file, convert it into a `dict` and perform all sorts of operations to it. And only when you want to print out an output or write to a file or return an output you convert to a `json` since `json.dump()` is expensive, it adds `2ms` (approx) of overhead which might not seem much but when your code is running in `500 microseconds` it's almost 4 times.

### Other Recommendations

After seeing your code, I realize you're coming from a `java` background and while in `java` the `getThis()` or `getThat()` is a great way to module your code since we represent our code in `classes` in `java`, in `python` it just causes problems in the `readability` of the code as mentioned in the `PEP 8` [style guide for python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

I've updated the code below:

```
import json


def get_contents_from_json(file_path)-> dict:
    """
    Reads the contents of the json file into a dict
    :param file_path:
    :return: A dictionary of all contents in the file.
    """
    try:
        with open(file_path) as file:
            contents = file.read()
            return json.loads(contents)
    except json.JSONDecodeError:
        print('Error while reading json file')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f'The JSON file was not found at the given path: \n{file_path}')


def write_to_json_file(metadata, timestamp, content, file_path):
    """
    Creates a dict of all the data and then writes it into the file
    :param metadata: The meta data
    :param timestamp: the timestamp
    :param content: the content
    :param file_path: The file in which json needs to be written
    :return: None
    """
    output_dict = dict(metadata=metadata, timestamp=timestamp, content=content)
    with open(file_path, 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(output_dict, outfile, sort_keys=True, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)


def main(input_file_path, output_file_path):
    # get a dict from the loaded json
    data = get_contents_from_json(input_file_path)

    # the print() supports multiple args so you don't need multiple print statements
    print('JSON:', json.dumps(data), 'Loaded JSON as dict:', data, sep='\n')

    try:
        # load your data from the dict instead of the methods since it's more pythonic
        metadata = data['metadata']
        timestamp = data['timestamp']
        content = data['content']

        # just cumulating your print statements
        print("Metadata:", metadata, "Timestamp:", timestamp, "Content:", content, sep='\n')

        # write your json to the file.
        write_to_json_file(metadata, timestamp, content, output_file_path)
    except KeyError:
        print('Could not find proper keys to in the provided json')
    except TypeError:
        print('There is something wrong with the loaded data')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main('stack.json', 'stack-out.json')
```

---

### Advantages of the above code:

1. More `Modular` and hence easily unit testable
2. Handling of `exceptions`
3. Readable
4. More pythonic
5. Comments because they are just awesome!

Comment: Great answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### Solution:

Change the `write_json_to_file(...)` method like this:

```
def write_json_to_file(file_name, json_content):
    with open(file_name, 'w') as file:
        file.write(json_content)
```

### Explanation:

The problem is, that when you're calling `write_json_to_file(STACK_OUT_JSON, created_json)` at the end of your script, the variable `created_json` contains a `string` - it's the JSON representation of the dictionary created in the `create_json(...)` function. But inside the `write_json_to_file(file_name, json_content)`, you're calling:

```
json.dump(json_content, file)
```

You're telling the `json` module write the JSON representation of variable `json_content` (which contains a `string`) into the file. And JSON representation of a `string` is a single value encapsulated in double-quotes (`"`), with all the double-quotes it contains escaped by `\`.
What you want to achieve is to simply write the value of the `json_content` variable into the file and not have it first JSON-serialized again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!