# How to write all the returned data into JSON file using Python?

Tags: json, python-3.x, list, loops

How to write the returned dict into a **json file**.

until now I am able to returned the correct data and print it, but when I tried to write it into a JSON file it just write the last record.

I will appreciate any help to fix this

example :

## printed data:

```
[{"file Name": "test1.txt", "searched Word": "th", "number of occurence": 1}]
[{"file Name": "test2.txt", "searched Word": "th", "number of occurence": 1}]
```

## json file

```
[{"file Name": "test2.txt", "searched Word": "th", "number of occurence": 1}]
```

## code:

```
import re
import json
import os.path
import datetime


for counter, myLine in enumerate(textList):
    thematch=re.sub(searchedSTR,RepX,myLine)
    matches = re.findall(searchedSTR, myLine, re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)


    if len(matches) > 0:  

        # add one record for the match (add one because line numbers start with 1)
        d[matches[0]].append(counter + 1)
    self.textEdit_PDFpreview.insertHtml(str(thematch))
    '''
    loop over the selected file and extract 3 values:
    ==> name of file 
    ==> searched expression
    ==> number of occurence 
    '''
for match, positions in d.items():
    listMetaData = [{"file Name":fileName,"searched Word":match,"number of occurence":len(positions)}]
    jsondata = json.dumps(listMetaData)
    print("in the for loop ==>jsondata: \n{0}".format(jsondata))

    '''
    create a folder called 'search_result' that includes all the result of the searching as JSON file 
    where the system check if the folder exist will continue if not the system create the folder
    insode the folder the file will be created as ==> today_searchResult.js
    '''
if not(os.path.exists("./search_result")):
    try:
        #print(os.mkdir("./search_result"))
        #print(searchResultFoder)

        today = datetime.date.today()
        fileName = "{}_searchResult.json".format(today)
        #fpJ = os.path.join(os.mkdir("./search_result"),fileName)
        #print(fpJ)
        with open(fileName,"w") as jsf:
            jsf.write(jsondata)
            print("finish writing")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: You want to write multiple json records into a single file? `open(fileName,"w")` overwrites the file each time. Use append mode "a".

Comment: what i want is to write multiple json record each time the system run.

Comment: But... do you want to write them all into a single file? You create one unique filename per day, but since you open the file in _write_ instead of _append_ mode, the file is overwritten for each record.

Comment: If you want separate files for each record, the problem is at `fileName = "{}_searchResult.json".format(today)`.

Comment: @tdelaney i can add time to the file name so it become unique name for each time the  system run. .... but what i mean that on each time the system run it may return several record so these i need to write it them all in the same JSON file.

Comment: @tdelaney i think this have something with the loop

Comment: Yes, it is the loop. Every time you open the file in "w" mode, you overwrite its previous contents. To put all of the records in a single file, you want to append - `with open(fileName,"a") as jsf:`

Comment: so how to fix this loop?

Comment: Opening the file in append mode didn't work?

Comment: yes it work as append mode thank you.

can you help me with another problem ?

Comment: I've answered a question yesterday [here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49698712/3766231) If that doesn't help can you share a dummy script that we can simply copy and run it to find out? There are inputs that are missing. and the class too

Comment: If you have another problem, post it as a new question. Try to boil any code down to a simple example that focuses on that one thing. By asking a new question, you get more eyeballs looking at it.

Comment: i already post a new question[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49708847/how-to-create-a-list-of-dictionaries-using-python/49709218#49709218]