# how to create a list of dictionaries using python

Tags: python, json, list, loops, dictionary

I have a function that returns a list where I serialized into a json object and write it to a JSON file.

the result is correct but the problem is that it returns each record in the separated list.

what I want is to return one list with multiple dictionary items.

## example:

## returned result:

```
[{"file Name": "test1.txt", "searched Word": "th", "number of occurence": 1}][{"file Name": "test2.txt", "searched Word": "th", "number of occurence": 1}]
```

## expected result

```
[
 {
   "file Name": "test1.txt",
   "searched Word": "th", 
   "number of occurence": 1
  }
  {
   "file Name": "test2.txt",
   "searched Word": "th",
   "number of occurence": 1
  }
 ]
```

how can I achieve this?

## code:

```
    for counter, myLine in enumerate(textList):
                thematch=re.sub(searchedSTR,RepX,myLine)
                matches = re.findall(searchedSTR, myLine, re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)


                if len(matches) > 0:  

                    # add one record for the match (add one because line numbers start with 1)
                    d[matches[0]].append(counter + 1)
                self.textEdit_PDFpreview.insertHtml(str(thematch))
                '''
                loop over the selected file and extract 3 values:
                ==> name of file 
                ==> searched expression
                ==> number of occurence 
                '''
listMetaData=[]
                for match, positions in d.items():
                    listMetaData.append({"file Name":fileName,"searched Word":match,"number of occurence":len(positions)})
                jsondata = json.dumps(listMetaData)
                print(jsondata)
```

Comment: It seems to me you're missing a couple ',' in your returned and expected results?

Comment: `json dumps` returns a string representing a json object from a dict.

Comment: can you share the value of the variable textList that get's passed to the first for loop

Comment: @iam.Carrot the value is `with open(currentFile) as ctf:
                ctfRead = ctf.read()
                textList = ctfRead.split('\n')`

Answer (score 0):

You can change this by changing the way you save your data:

```
listMetaData = []
for match, positions in d.items():
    listMetaData.append({"file Name":fileName,"searched Word":match,"number of occurence":len(positions)})
jsondata = json.dumps(listMetaData)
print(jsondata)
```

This way you'll save

```
 [{dict: 1}, {dict: 2}]
```

Instead of

```
[{dict:1}] [{dict: 2}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code creates a list immediatly then prints every list. Your question is unclear exactly what you want, but I believe you want a list of all of the metadata objects. You would do that by changing the code:

```
for match, positions in d.items():
            listMetaData = [{"file Name":fileName,"searched Word":match,"number of occurence":len(positions)}]
            jsondata = json.dumps(listMetaData)
            print(jsondata)
```

to

```
all_metadata = []
for match, positions in d.items():
    meta_data = {"file Name":fileName,"searched Word":match,"number of occurence":len(positions)}
    all_metadata.append(meta_data)

json_data = json.dumps(all_metadata)
print(json_data)
return json_data
```

note that python is meant to not use camel case for variables, but snake case. Also, indentation should be with 4 spaces (or a tab), not 10 spaces.

Comment: i tried your answer but still getting the same result ==> multiple list

Comment: then you are doing something wrong. If you want the string to be formatted better add `indent=4` as a paremeter to json.dumps

Comment: i tried to add indent =4  it still the same result  that is one file that includes multiple lists where each list handle one dictionary.... what i want is to have one file that includes one list that handle multiple dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

You could just merge your lists together like new_list = list_1 + list_2

Answer (score 0):

**Quick and dirty:**

You need to create your output list before any `for` loop, remove the brackets from `listMetaData` variable, append `listMetaData` to the output list, and move the `json.dumps` below the `for` loop.

**Explained:**

So, you want to create a `list` of `dictionaries`. This means you need a list to put any dictionaries into.

What's currently happening in your code is that you are creating a list for each match, using brackets.

```
for match, positions in d.items():
        listMetaData = [{"file Name":fileName,"searched Word":match,"number of occurence":len(positions)}]
        jsondata = json.dumps(listMetaData)
        print(jsondata)
```

Try storing the list in a variable before you initiate the `for`loop. Then do a json dump of the resulting list.

```
output_list = []
for match, positions in d.items():
    listMetaData = {"key": value, etc..}
    output_list.append(listMetaData)
jsondata = json.dumps(output_list)
print(jsondata)
```

Comment: I TRIED THIS  but still THE SAME RESULT 
`listMetaData=[]
                for match, positions in d.items():
                    listMetaData.append({"file Name":fileName,"searched Word":match,"number of occurence":len(positions)})
                jsondata = json.dumps(listMetaData)
                print(jsondata)`

Comment: still not succeed to fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code to convert multiple lists of dictionaries into single list of dictionaries.

I assume your json has comma separated  i.e there is comma between each list.

```
[{"file Name": "test1.txt", "searched Word": "th", "number of occurence": 1}],[{"file Name": "test2.txt", "searched Word": "th", "number of occurence": 1}]
```

**Sample code :**

```
myDict = []
myJsonvar = [{"file Name": "test1.txt", "searched Word": "th", "number of occurence": 1}],[{"file Name": "test2.txt", "searched Word": "th", "number of occurence": 1}]

for idx,jstrings in enumerate(myJsonvar) :
    for inx, elem in enumerate(jstrings) :
        myDict.append(myJsonvar[idx][inx])

print(myDict)
```

**Output :**

```
[{'file Name': 'test1.txt', 'searched Word': 'th', 'number of occurence': 1}, {'file Name': 'test2.txt', 'searched Word': 'th', 'number of occurence': 1}]
```

This output will also be comma separated single list dictionaries.

**Other approach :**
if you don't want to make list of dictionaries or append comma between lists .

your can try this code :

```
import re

import yaml


myListOfDict = []
myJsonvar = '[{"file Name": "test1.txt", "searched Word": "th", "number of occurence": 1}][{"file Name": "test2.txt", "searched Word": "th", "number of occurence": 1}]'

mylist = myJsonvar.split("][")

for lst in mylist :
    updateVar = re.sub(r'[\[\]]', '',lst)
    myListOfDict.append(yaml.load(updateVar))

print(myListOfDict)
```

**Output**

```
[{'file Name': 'test1.txt', 'searched Word': 'th', 'number of occurence': 1}, {'file Name': 'test2.txt', 'searched Word': 'th', 'number of occurence': 1}]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: can you help me with this question ?  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49750393/how-to-change-the-color-of-specified-word-in-python]

Comment: Please accept this answer if that is what you were looking for

Comment: I will take a look into the said issue

Answer (score -1):

```
[dict1, dict2]
```

You can use the usual list syntax with comma separated objects where the objects happen to be dictionaries.

Comment: the list will contains as dict1 ==> `[{"file Name": "test1.txt", "searched Word": "th", "number of occurence": 1}` dict2 ==> `{"file Name": "test2.txt", "searched Word": "th", "number of occurence": 1}]`