# How to to check if a folder doesn't exist to create a file inside of it?

Tags: python, json, list, directory, writefile

I am trying to check if folder exist if not the system create it and a JSON file will be written inside this folder.

The problem is that the system create an empty folder and displays this error:

```
None

 the selected file is not readble because :  [WinError 183] Cannot
 create a file when that file already exists: './search_result'
 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

`None` is the result of: `print(searchResultFoder)`.

The code is:

```
if not(os.path.exists("./search_result")):                                      
                    today = time.strftime("%Y%m%d__%H-%M")
                    jsonFileName = "{}_searchResult.json".format(today)
                    fpJ = os.path.join(os.mkdir("./search_result"),jsonFileName)
                    print(fpJ)
with open(fpJ,"a") as jsf:
                    jsf.write(jsondata)
                    print("finish writing")
```

Comment: `mkdir` doesn't return any value, so you can't print it, so you're assigning `None` to `searchResultFoder`.

Comment: @jean Rostan  i know that  so how to fix this ??

Comment: Please [edit] your question and fix the indentation of your sample code.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.  You create a new folder with a constant name, but then use `searchResultFoder` instead of that name.  Then you seem to expect that your new folder will have files in it ... *while you try to create it a second time*.
We can't **fix** code that seems to disagree with itself.

Comment: @Prune when you say **while you try to create it a second time** where this happen in my code because what i want is .....1) check if folder exist if not create it   2) write the JSON FILE  inside this created folder.

Comment: Then use the folder you just created.  Your code calls `mkdir` a second time, when you *know* it already exists.  That's guaranteed to raise an exception.  You already *have* the folder name; use it.

Comment: i delete the var searchResultFoder  and try to create the folder inside **OS.PATH.JOIN** BUT THE SYSTEM still display this error :

**expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
'NoneType' object is not iterable**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issues with code :

- **Case Directory Doesn't exist :** `os.mkdir("./search_result")` in `fpJ =
  os.path.join(os.mkdir("./search_result"),jsonFileName)` returns
  nothing you have assumed it will return you the path of the created
  folder. which is incorrect.
- **Case Directory exists :** In case when condition `if not(os.path.exists("./search_result")):`
  is false json file name will be undefined and throw and exception

.
Full working example of code which is doing the following.
1) check if folder exist if not create it 
2) write the JSON FILE inside this created folder.

```
import json
import os
import time

jsondata = json.dumps({"somedata":"Something"})
folderToCreate = "search_result"
today = time.strftime("%Y%m%d__%H-%M")
jsonFileName = "{}_searchResult.json".format(today)

if not(os.path.exists(os.getcwd()+os.sep+folderToCreate)):
                    os.mkdir("./search_result")

fpJ = os.path.join(os.getcwd()+os.sep+folderToCreate,jsonFileName)
print(fpJ)

with open(fpJ,"a") as jsf:
                    jsf.write(jsondata)
                    print("finish writing")
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you this solve the problem... i have another problem  can you help me with ? 

the created file includes **multiple lists with 1 dictionary**  ... where what i want is to have **1 list  with  multiple dictionaries itmes**

Comment: sure i can, can you share some example of the dictionary and the lists ? I will suggest you to ask a separate question for  this. It will help others with the similar queries.

Comment: Accept the answer if it fixes the stated problem

Comment: this is the other question but till now no one was able to fix the issue [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49708847/how-to-create-a-list-of-dictionaries-using-python?noredirect=1#comment86433963_49708847]