# how to change the color of specified word in python

Tags: python, html, regex, file

How to change the color of selected word in a text file using python?

The below function read from file and match the requested word if its found it change the color of the expression into red.

The problem is that when i run the program the HTML tag  is displayed in the textBox  as text and not as a color  like this.

```
 "<b><span style='color:white;mso-themecolor:background1;background:black;mso-highlight:black'>"+searchedSTR+"
```

"
I will appreciate any help with this problem

## code:

```
def readFile(self, currentFile):

        self.textEdit_PDFpreview.clear()        
        searchedSTR = self.lineEditSearch.text()
        try:
            with open(currentFile) as ctf:
                ctfRead = ctf.read()               
                fileName = os.path.basename(currentFile)        
                RepX = "<b><span style='color:white;mso-themecolor:background1;background:black;mso-highlight:black'>"+st+"</span></b>"

                thematch=re.sub(searchedSTR,RepX,ctfRead)
                print("the match \n{}".format(thematch))
                matches = re.findall(searchedSTR, ctfRead, re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)                    
                print(" matches is: \n{}".format(matches))

                if matches:  
                    self.textEdit_PDFpreview.insertHtml(thematch)
                else:
                    print("Not Found")
                    self.textEdit_PDFpreview.insertHtml(str("no match found"))
```

## functional code :

```
import  mainwindow

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class appwindow(mainwindow.Ui_MainWindow):
        def __init__(self,winObj:QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
                self.winObj = winObj
                self.setupUi(winObj)
                self.winObj.show()
                self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.changeColor)

        def changeColor(self):
                st ="test"
                x = "<b><span style='color:white;mso-themecolor:background1;background:black;mso-highlight:black'>"+st+"</span></b>"

                self.textEdit.insertHtml(x)


if __name__ == "__main__":

        import sys
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        ImainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        ui = appwindow(ImainWindow)
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Please start your sentences with upper case letters and use correct interpunctiation. This would be more polite to the readers which maybe would answer your question.

Comment: Also provide a minimal working example. It is unclear what you are trying to do here. The question looks more related to string manipulation and not to html or color things.

Comment: @buhtz no the question about how to change the color of the matching expression  because what i tried is not return the correct result

Comment: Don't waste our times. Read my first comment and try again! Correct interpunctation!

Comment: @buhtz i improved the question

Comment: This is still not a **working** example.

Answer (score 0):

the function work after i changed the statement :

```
  self.textEdit_PDFpreview.insertHtml(thematch)
```

to

```
 self.textEdit_PDFpreview.setHtml(str(thematch))
```